# The set of all upper bounds of a set in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected. Is there any deeper significance of this fact?

Tags: real-analysis

If $u_1$ and $u_2$ belong to $U$ the set of all upper bounds of a set in $\mathbb{R}$ then $[u_1,u_2]$ is contained in $U$ and $u$ belongs to $U$ implies $[u,\infty)$ belongs to $U$. Is there any significance of this fact?

Comment: Probably not. It's just an interval.

Comment: Basically all this means is that if $u$ is a upper bound of a set $X$, then (evidently) all $v\geq u$ are upper bounds of the set $X$. An easy consequence of the transitivity of the linear order.

Comment: Yes but is there any deeper consequence of U being connected?